# 12.04 Is it possible to change "Home" icon on the launcher?

Tags: 12.04, themes, icons

Is there a way to change the home icon **without** changing folder icon?

[image: See image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple guide, I think it can help you.

[How To: Custom Icon Themes](http://geekitdown.com/blog/how-to-custom-icon-themes-ubuntu/)

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the «Home» icon in the launcher, you have to do the following.

1.- Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

2.- Copy (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) in terminal

`gedit .local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`

3.- Copy (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) in new document

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Home Folder
Comment=Open your personal folder
Exec=nautilus %U
Icon=folder
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.0.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
Actions=Window;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

4.- Change **folder** in **Icon=folder** for the icon you are willing to use, for instance, **folder-home** or another image locally saved.

5.- Save document

6.- Log out